# Android Webview Content Overlapping While Using Transparent Background

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview, transparent

I found that this question has been asked before [How to resolve overlapping the content of the webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898196/how-to-resolve-overlapping-the-content-of-the-webview-closed) here, but it was closed for some reason. But here is what happens. I have created a webview, applied transparent background, but when i try to load something, and reload something again, the older content will still remain on the webview and the newer one will overlap it. Here is a picture that explains it.

[image: Overlapped]

So i am creating a jokes application, and i have added webview. Then i added transparency and the random joke button reloads the webpage so that the webview can get another joke. But it just overlapps instead. Any solutions? Here is my piece of code

```
        Button random = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reload);
    final WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    web.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    String selected = (String) getIntent().getCharSequenceExtra("selected");
    final String url = "http://someurl.com/?s=dirty&x=" + selected;
    web.loadUrl(url);

    random.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            web.loadUrl(url);
        }
    });
```

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try before doing `web.loadUrl(url);` doing `web.clearView();`

See [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#clearView%28%29).

Comment: That makes the app really really slow, and is not the perfect fix.

Comment: @Abhinav Down-voting is for if you find the answer not useful, and not for "not the perfect fix", but in any case I somehow don't think that doing a call to `clearView` between loads should slow down your app perceptibly at all. Note that I'm not suggesting another load, but simply before the load that you have to do anyway call `clearView`.

Comment: "clearView()"  is deprecated in API Level 18 try " loadUrl("about:blank"); " instead