# android webview previous content in background

Tags: javascript, android, webview, loading, visual-glitch

Not sure if this is a problem due to using transparent backgrounds, but I am using a webview to show a webpage to the user, however if the user loads another url from a link or javascript is used to dynamically insert new content into the page the rendering seems to glitch.

By glitch I mean that the page remains in the background whilst the new content / page is loaded in the foreground. They end up overlapping and making everything very unreadable.

I have hardwareacceleration turned off on my webview to enable transparent background, could that be causing the problem?

It's similar to this question [Android Webview Content Overlapping While Using Transparent Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365807/android-webview-content-overlapping-while-using-transparent-background).

Many thanks.

Comment: If the Problem is similar then solution is also similar. Have you tried the solution that given there.

Comment: I tried to implement that solution within the webviewclient's "onPageStarted" function however that didn't work. But because this also occurs when javascript interacts with the webpage it won't be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the fact I had transparent background on, I removed this and it was okay. Not the best solution but one that is preferred over having glitchy graphics. I mimiced the transparent background by matching the CSS background properties to that of where my WebView was positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on Google TV boxes and managed to fix this by forcing WebKit to redraw the DOM from jQuery as in:

```
$('<style></style>').appendTo($(document.body)).remove();
```

or (if you don't like jQuery):

```
document.body.style.display='none';
document.body.offsetHeight;
document.body.style.display='block';
```

You can inject either of the code fragments dynamically from Android as in `webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ /* put the force-redraw-code here */ })()")` or do it directly from JavaScript after you altered the DOM.

More related fixes at [How can I force WebKit to redraw/repaint to propagate style changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485365/how-can-i-force-webkit-to-redraw-repaint-to-propagate-style-changes)